# Is it possible that sell NFT-Token by ERC20 token which is created by me?

Tags: ethereum, cryptocurrency, nft

I want to create a website for minting my NFT-TOKENS. It seems the websites sell NFT-tokens by minting ETH on Ethereum, Now I would use my token(ERC20) instead of ETH. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sell your NFT tokens for your ERC 20 tokens, but you will still need ETH to perform transactions on the network.